# Ошибки E2094 'operator+' not implemented in type 'string' for arguments of type 'const char *' и `char`

Tags: c++

```
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream.h>
   #include <conio.h>
   using namespace std;
int main()
{
  std::string Start, End;
   int dl, i;
   {
    for (i=1; i<=dl; i++)
   {

       switch (Start[i]) {
         case 'а':
            End = End + "a";
            break;
         case 'А':
            End = End + "A";
            break;
           //остальной код
         default:
            End = End + Start[i];
            break;
      }
   }
   }
     std::cout<<Start[i];

      getch();
   }
```

При компиляции появляются такие ошибки:

> [BCC32 Error] File1.cpp(15): E2094 'operator+' not implemented in type 'string' for arguments of type 'const char *'
>  Full parser context
>    File1.cpp(6): parsing: int main()

Вторая ошибка:

> [BCC32 Error] File1.cpp(22): E2094 'operator+' not implemented in type 'string' for arguments of type 'char'
>      Full parser context
>        File1.cpp(6): parsing: int main()

Answer (score 2):

Так оператор + вообще не перегружен для string. Зато определен += :

```
End += 'A';
End += "A";
```

Еще string имеет метод append()

Исправленный текст

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string Start, End;
    cin >> Start;
   int dl = Start.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < dl; i++)
   {

       switch (Start[i]) {
         case 'а':
            End += 'a';
            break;
         case 'А':
            End += 'A';
            break;
           //остальной код
         default:
            End += Start[i];
            break;
      }

   }
     cout<<End<<endl;

    getchar();
    getchar();   
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: то есть поддержка оператора + для `string` - это несоответствие стандарту?

Comment: сделал так, но теперь ошибка после того как я ввожу букву 
Debugger exeption notification 
write of adress ...

Comment: Да потому что код написан непонятно как. Срочно учиться.

Comment: есть конкретный ввод, в цикле замена букв, есть конкретный вывод, а вот чего не работают даже вы не знаете, вместо того что бы посылать учится сами бы учебник полистали, а в этом совете я не нуждаюсь

Comment: и напрасно )))

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey, кстати, все Вам уже разжевал. Просто не хочу повторять его мысли.

Comment: для того что бы открыть учебник мне советов для этого не нужно, а если сами не знаете то лучше промолчать чем давать советы НИ О ЧЕМ

Comment: Вам написать исправленный текст? Пожалуйста, но чуть позже.

Comment: я сделал как он, оно мне просто дублирует написанное, а если не трудно то напишите пожалуйста, я посмотрю как ваше отличается от моего!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

вот это исправило пару ошибок

```
cin >> Start;
dl=Start.length();
```

и перед циклом должно быть это

Comment: а чт ов самому цикле должно быть, а то столько вариантов что уже запутался!

Comment: а в цикле ничего править не надо, и не будет ошибок компиляции и выполнения.
у меня на g++ и Visual Studio все OK

Comment: я к своему исходному коду добавил то что вы написали, и у меня просто дублирует а не переводит

Comment: а что по вашему оно должно делать? вы спрашивали про ошибки - их исправили))))

Comment: как что переводить, зачем мне дублирование когда я четко написал о переводе???

Comment: каким макаром оно должно переводить???

Comment: все, я все организовал, и переводит лучше всех)